# How can multiple Service Accounts access the same data?

Tags: permissions, google-api, google-fusion-tables, service-accounts

I'm using Google Service Accounts that are both part of the same Project to view and edit Fusion Tables data. I've set up two service accounts one that has an editor role and one that has a view role. Everything works fine with a single service account. Adding another Service Account, it seems to access an entirely different repository.

Giving both Service Accounts editor roles I can view and edit data that the other Service Account cannot see.

This behavior seems contrary to everything I've read. Are fusion tables implemented incorrectly? My understanding is that service accounts in the same project should access the same data. How can I work around this to have one service account that is view only and another that can edit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've confirmed that each service account has its own repository or "drive". It would appear that the service accounts belonging to the same Project is meaningless for the purposes of accessing Fusion Tables.

It appears Fusion Tables must be shared with other service accounts for those accounts to have access. I was able to confirm this by creating with my google account in my google drive and then sharing the document with the service accounts. see below:[image: Sharing settings]

I'm still not certain what purpose roles have for fusion tables when access is controlled at the sharing level.

Going forward I will create the fusion table in my personal account and share it with the service accounts as pictured above.

Note: In order for a view only permissioned account to use "Select * From.." the table must be marked as "downloadable".